# Calculate the number years between a historic date and today

Tags: ms-access

I am relatively new to Access - in a Query how do I calculate the number of  years between a historic date and today- date is in the format 00/00/0000

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for `DateDiff("yyyy", Now, TheDate)` this will return the year number between `TheDate` and the current date.

You can use `d` or `ww` (instead of 'yyyy') if you want to learn the amount of day or week between the dates.

For detailed information you can look into this link:
https://support.office.com/en-us/article/DateDiff-Function-e6dd7ee6-3d01-4531-905c-e24fc238f85f